# how to pass html input type button name value to jsp function

Tags: html, jsp

I want to pass html input type=button name to html function. Following is the code I tried but it doesn't help:

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" name="JSP" onclick=<%=delete1(%>this.name<%);%>/>
<%!
void delete1(String name){
<%name%>
}
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really a classic one: The key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is send to the browser) and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the already generated response.

Comment: So what changes would you recommend in the code? Should I opt for JavaScript function?

Comment: Yes, use pure JS. If you need to communicate with the back-end, use [AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4113258/3511123).